# C++ ignore and clear buffer

Tags: c++, iostream

```
    int position;
    afile.open("EmployeeInfo.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);   

    char name[80];
    cout << "\nEdit Employee Info" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    cout << "New Employee Username: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        cin.getline(name, 80);
    bool flag = true;
```

hi all this is a code fragment of my program that i'm currently doing. most of the functionality are fine, with the exception that i need to press Enter twice to receive the getline data. can anyone point out to me where im doing wrongly?

last input prior to this is a integer input using cin >> choice; going into a switch.
i do not have any errors with other functions even though they are doing the exact same thing. literally exact.

for eg. no errors with the following

```
afile.open("EmployeeInfo.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);   

char name[80];
cout << "\nAdd Employee Info" << endl;
cout << "---------------------" << endl;
cout << "New Employee Username: ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
cin.getline(name, 80);
```

Okay here's the surrounding codes.

the function is called in another function

```
    cout << "Your Choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: cout << "Create Holiday Package" << endl;
        break;
        case 2: cout << "Delete Holiday Package" << endl;
        break;
        case 3: cout << "Edit Holiday Package" << endl;
        break;
        case 4: addEmployee(afile, num, e);
        break;
        case 5: delEmployee(afile, num, e);
        break;
        case 6: editEmployee(afile, num, e);
        break; ....// to be continue case
  }//end case
```

and this is the interaction i have with the cmd

## Welcome to Employee Login Screen

Please Enter Username: Daniel Roberts

Please Enter Password: Daniel1234

Login successful

General Manager Menu

1)Create Holiday Package

2)Delete Holiday Package

3)Edit Holiday Package

4)Create a Staff Account

5)Delete a Staff Account

6)Edit a Staff Account

7)View Stats of Booking Packages

8)Quit

Your Choice: 6

Edit Employee Info

---

New Employee Username: John Smith

<- weird space here that i need to press enter to get rid of

Enter new name:

Comment: I think you need to show a little more surrounding code, as well as showing the actual input/output and the expected input/output (i.e. show a session as it is with your current code, and what it should look like).

Comment: Can you give us a copy-paste of your program in one code block please? It helps us to see what's happening before/after the other.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `cin.ignore()` call, it will read until it has either read 100 characters or one of those characters are a newline. So to satisfy it you have to enter e.g. a newline.

Comment: hmm i understand what u mean, but when i type in the cin.getline, doesnt that already satisfy the \n function?

for e.g my input is
cin.getline(name,80) <-- for this part i typed in name A enter

i've tried removing the ignore function, and it seems that a input that is lingering in the buffer is there, thus skipping my getline function.

Comment: @user3245403 When you do `ignore` followed by `getline` you are doing *two* input operations. Both ended with a newline.

Comment: Oh okay i get it, but, when i removed the ignore function, this happens 
New Employee Username: Record is not found.
the cin.getline was skipped. 
how can i go about this?